# How to bypass Cloudflare restrictions with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, cloudflare

The following script ends up throwing the error *"Attention Required! | Cloudflare"* when I try to get data using `response.css('title::text').get()` as a test.

**Scrapy Spider:**

```
import scrapy

class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "avvo"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.avvo.com/attorneys/84025-ut-jason-hunter-284784/reviews.html',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def __init__(self):
        self.called = False
        
        self.data = {}
        
    def parse(self, response):
        if not self.called:
            self.called = True

            self.data["website"] = response.css('title::text').get()
            
            yield self.data
```

**Result:**

```
'Attention Required! | Cloudflare'
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @njzk2 I want to bypass 'Attention Required! | Cloudflare' restrictions on the website that I try to crawl.

Comment: Are you asking for help bypassing the security settings on someone else's web site? That seems uncool.

Comment: @KentonVarda No, I'm looking for ethically sound methods to bypass reCAPTCHA because the scraper will be deployed to AWS Lambda so customers can use it.

Comment: The "ethically sound" solution is to contact the site owner and ask them to allow-list your scraper.

Comment: @KentonVarda If you don't know, just say you don't know. Stop asking too many unrelated and unhelpful questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium to bypass cloudflare.

```
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


    def start_requests(self):
        # Driver Path and Options for Selenium is done in settings file
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='http://example.com',
            wait_time=3,
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get selenium web driver from response object
        driver = response.meta['driver']
     

        # Grab Modified response from webdriver
        page_html = driver.page_source
        pageResponseObj = Selector(text=page_html)
```